# Join 2 tables with filter

Tags: sql

I have a question how do I join two tables while also filtering it?

Basically I have two tables, Please see attached:
[image]

**Driver Status Location Table**

[image]

**Vehicles Table**

The plan here is only get all driver_id with the following:

- status = 0
- is_online = true
- vehicle_size = small

Below is my current sql syntax for getting all nearest drivers with filter except for the vehicle_size.

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT *,
    (
        (
            (
                acos(
                    sin(( 14.231 * pi() / 180)) *
                    sin(( lat * pi() / 180)) + cos(( 14.231 * pi() /180 )) *
                    cos(( lat * pi() / 180)) * cos((( 121.321 - lng) * pi()/180))
                )
            ) * 180/pi()
        ) * 60 * 1.1515 * 1.609344
    ) as distance FROM driver_status_location
) driver_status_location
WHERE distance <= 5 AND status=0 AND is_online=true
ORDER BY distance
LIMIT 5;
```

The only missing here is to filter the vehicle_size which is on another table.

Please let me know if that does not make sense or do I need to add more details. Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: Please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. If you *are* using SQL Server, the above will error; `LIMIT` is not a recognised keyword in T-SQL.

Comment: Thank you for editing @Larnu . Hmm not sure about it. It works in node.js when I tried the `LIMIT`

Comment: *You* need to [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS though. The fact that `LIMIT` did work further cements you aren't using SQL Server.

Comment: Add some more sample table data, also specify the expected result. All as properly formatted text (no images, no links.)

Answer (score 2):

It is just example on which you can exercise in order to fit your own needs. You can join two tables as follow. :

```
SELECT `VT`.`distance`, `VT`.`status` 
FROM `vehiclesTable` AS `VT`
INNER JOIN driver_status_location AS `DSL` ON `DSL`.driver_id=`VT`.driver_id
WHERE 
  `VT`.`distance` <= 5 AND 
 `VT`.`status` = 0 AND 
 `VT`.`is_online` = true;
```

It is simple example how to join two tables. It may not help you straight forward but you can use it as idea to start from it.

Basically in order to JOIN two tables you have 4 ways to do so

1. **INNER JOIN** - Retrieves records that have matching values in both tables
2. **CROSS JOIN** - Retrieves all records when there is a match in either left or right table
3. **LEFT JOIN** - Retrieves all records from the left table, and the matched records from the right table.
4. **RIGHT JOIN** - Retrieves all records from the right table, and the matched records from the left table.

Also in order to join two or more tables together the best way is to do so by using columns that are **foreign key** columns.
Also I believe subquery are slowing down the query as general.

I hope that information will helps you in same way or at least will give you a direction.

Comment: Note that those back-ticks will result in a syntax error on most dbms's.

Comment: `FULL OUTER JOIN` - Returns the matching rows, and the rows from the left table without matches in the right table, and the rows from the right table without matches in the left table.

Comment: thanks for this! Let me try this one

Comment: this is called an answer. thanks for your valuable answer. It helps me to learn something.